# Find $\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\frac{1}{\epsilon^3}\int\limits_{0}^{\infty}\sin(\epsilon\cdot f(t))d\mu(t)$ given $\int\limits_{0}^{\infty}f=0$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, limits, measure-theory

Let $(\mathbb {R},\mathcal B, \mu)$ be finite measure space, where $\mathcal B$ is the Borel sigma-algebra on $\mathbb R$.
Let $f$ be an integrable function such that $$ \int\limits_{0}^{\infty}f(x)d\mu = 0.$$
Also assume $f^2$ is integrable, i.e $\int\limits_\mathbb {R} f^2d\mu<\infty.$

find $$\lim_{\epsilon \to 0}\frac{1}{\epsilon ^ 3}\int\limits_{0}^{\infty}\sin(\epsilon\cdot f(t))d\mu(t)$$

Comment: "Also assume $f^2$ is integrable, i.e $\int\limits_\mathbb {R} f^2<\infty.$" Is that integral with respect to $\mu$ or with respect to Lebesgue measure?

Comment: @zhw. With respect to $\mu$. I edited the question, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $f\in L^4$ then the answer is $-\frac{1}{6} \int_0^{\infty} f^3 d\mu$. There is consequently no consistent answer when we only know that $f^2$ is integrable.

Indeed, if $f\in L^4$ then write
$$ \sin\left(\epsilon f\left(t\right) \right) = \epsilon f\left(t\right) - \frac{1}{6} \epsilon^3 f\left(t\right)^3 + \frac{\sin\left(c_t\right)}{24} \epsilon^4 f\left(t\right)^4, $$
and integrate:
$$ \frac{1}{\epsilon^3} \int_0^{\infty} \sin\left(\epsilon f\left(t\right)\right) d\mu = -\frac{1}{6} \int_0^{\infty} f^3 d\mu + \frac{\epsilon}{24} \int_0^{\infty} \sin\left(c_t\right)f^4\left(t\right) d\mu\left(t\right)  . $$
The error term (i.e. the last term on the right) can be bounded as follows, using $\left|\sin\left(c_t\right)\right| \leq 1$:
$$ \frac{\epsilon}{24} \left|\int_0^{\infty} \sin\left(c_t\right)f^4\left(t\right) d\mu\left(t\right)\right| \leq \left(\frac{\int_0^{\infty} f^4 d\mu}{24}\right) \epsilon \xrightarrow[\epsilon\searrow 0]{}0, $$
since $f^4$ is integrable.

Comment: I don't think this is right. May you please explain how to bound the error term? What if $f(t)$ is very large?

Comment: @mathworker21 I added details. Have I convinced you?

Comment: @mathworker21 The example that you gave in your answer (can't comment on it yet) tracks with my suspicion, as it is indeed not in $L^4$ (and in fact not even in $L^3$, which is probably the natural condition).

Comment: Actually, I think that this just works as is for $f\in L^3$, since then $\sin\left(c_t\right)f\left(t\right)^4 \in L^1$ by linearity.

Comment: sorry, I said it wasn't right when I thought I had an example of $f \in L^4$ and $\lim \frac{1}{\epsilon^3} \int \sin(\epsilon f(t))dt = +\infty$. I now understand that $f \in L^4$ implies the limit is $-\frac{1}{6}\int f^3$. I don't see how $f \in L^3$ implies $\sin(c_t)f(t)^4 \in L^1$ (I don't know what "by linearity" means). Also, you should edit your answer: you now have a proof that the limit is $-\frac{1}{6}\int f^3$, not just a suspicion

Comment: I edited my answer as per your suggestion, and also upgraded it to cover any $f\in L^3$ with details regarding what I meant with "by linearity". Thank you for the feedback.

Comment: Doesn't $c_t$ depend on $\epsilon$?

Comment: Aaargh, yes. Reverted to $f\in L^4$. Surely there is a way to cover $f\in L^3$, maybe a density argument. Will think about this later.

Comment: @mathworker21 Of course! I couldn't comment on it directly before (reputation was under 50) but see [this comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3496140/find-lim-epsilon-to-0-frac1-epsilon3-int-limits-0-infty-sin-epsi/3496196?noredirect=1#comment7196872_3496196) as proof. :)

Comment: haha, sorry about that. i have mental issues

Answer (score 1):

The limit may be $+\infty$. Let $\mu$ be the Lebesgue measure. Let $f(t) = \epsilon_t\frac{1}{t^{.49}}$ where $\epsilon_t = 0$ for $t \le 0$ and $t \ge 1$, $\epsilon_t = 1$ for $0 < t \le t_*$, and $\epsilon_t = -1$ for $t_* < t < 1$, where $t_* = \frac{1}{2^{100/51}} \approx .25689$ is such that $\int_\mathbb{R} f(t)dt = 0$. Take $\epsilon > 0$ very small. Then, for $t < \epsilon^{1/.49}$, we have $\sin(\epsilon\frac{\epsilon_t}{t^{.49}}) \sim \epsilon\frac{\epsilon_t}{t^{.49}}$, so $\int_{\epsilon^{1/.49}}^1 \sin(\epsilon f(t))dt \sim \int_{\epsilon^{1/.49}}^1 \epsilon\frac{\epsilon_t}{t^{.49}}dt = -\epsilon\int_0^{\epsilon^{1/.49}} \frac{1}{t^{.49}}dt = -\frac{100}{51}\epsilon^{100/49}$.

Ok, I actually have to go now, but the leftover region is of size $\epsilon^{1/.49} = \omega(\epsilon^3)$, which is bad. The situation for $f(t) = \epsilon_t\frac{1}{t^{1/8}}$ is very different, since then $\sin(\epsilon f(t)) \sim \epsilon f(t)$ for all $t > \epsilon^8$, so the leftover error is at most $\epsilon^8$, which is small enough.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you please elaborate on why $\int_{0}^{1}sin(\epsilon\frac{\epsilon_t}{t^{1/8}})dt\neq 0$ ? I'm basically asking Why is the implicit choice of $\epsilon_t$ maintain $\int_{0}^{1}f(t)dt=0$, but $\int_{0}^{1}sin(\epsilon\frac{\epsilon_t}{t^{1/8}})dt \neq 0$

Comment: @TheHolyJoker I mean, why would it equal $0$? The choice of $\epsilon_t$'s was a precise choice to make the integral of $\epsilon_t\frac{1}{t^{1/8}}$ equal to $0$, but when we take sine, everything gets messed up. But I'll try to think of a construction and proof, if you want

Comment: That sounds very reasonable, but I'm still not convinced... I would greatly appreciate a constructive proof or even constructive 
proof sketch

Comment: Another question is, would $f(x)=sin(x)\chi_{[0,2\pi]}(x)$ work? for your reasoning?

Comment: no. since then $\sin(\epsilon f(x)) \approx \epsilon f(x)$, so integral would be $0$. give me a few more minutes for my answer, almost done

Comment: AHHHHHH. I was completely wrong. Thanks for making me (try to) write out a rigorous proof. Even though the integral won't be $0$, it will be arbitrarily close to $0$, since most of the $L^1$ mass of $f$ will be less than $\frac{1}{\epsilon}$, so we can do the approximation $\sin(\epsilon f(x)) \approx \epsilon f(x)$ nearly everywhere.

Comment: @TheHolyJoker see updated answer. All that's left to show is that $\int_0^{\epsilon^{1/.49}} \sin(\epsilon/t^{.49})dt < \frac{100}{51}\epsilon^{100/49}-\epsilon^{2.999}$, for example. The integral should be $c \epsilon^{100/49}$ for some $c < \frac{100}{51}$ I believe.